# Why would I need to put a $?

Tags: math-mode, errors

```
line 41: Missing $ inserted. ... of a single electron is -1.6 $\times$ 10^
line 41: Overfull \hbox (155.52795pt too wide) in paragraph
```

These are the error messages that are displayed and I don't know why. What do these mean?

Comment: so what does that mean?

Comment: note that you were lucky the `^` triggered an error: If the input had been `-1.6 $\times$ 10` there would be no error but the spacing, and possibly font, would be completely wrong, and you'd get a hyphen instead of a minus sign in front of the 1.6.

Comment: what I don't get is why it didn't let you insert the character '^'...

Answer (score 46):

Alternative: Don't worry yourself about such things or risk running in such errors, simply let the `siunitx` package do it for you:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

the charge of a single electron is \SI{-1.6e-19}{\coulomb} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

EDIT: With this many votes, I feel this answer needs something more creative to deserve the votes. So here an example how flexible `siunitx` is:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{phaistos}
\usepackage{starfont}
\usepackage{wasysym}

\DeclareSIUnit{\water}{\text{\Aquarius}}
\DeclareSIUnit{\duck}{\text{\PHdove}}
\DeclareSIUnit{\cookie}{\text{\PHshield}}
\DeclareSIUnit{\happy}{\smiley}


\begin{document}

A duck with cookies and water is happy: 

\[
\SI{1}{\duck} + \SI{3}{\cookie} + \si{\water} = \SI[parse-numbers=false]{\infty}{\happy} 
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: -1 that's not a real duck, it's a dove impersonating a duck.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It is a duck born in a dove body - the duck will surely be offended if called a dove :)

Comment: How is the “happy” physical unit defined? `$1\happy=...$`? :-)

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti `happy=-1*sad`, of course

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti Happy is a relative unit - it equals the caloric content of how much cake (or other sweets) it takes to make you happy :)

Answer (score 29):

The `$` character toggles math mode on and off, and the `^` in `10^` must be entered in math mode:

```
of a single electron is $-1.6 \times 10^x$
```

(Or whatever your exponent is.)

Comment: The error message doesn't show it being inserted that way.

Comment: @HSchmale tex doesn't understand the text so can not go back and correct earlier mistakes that did not generate an error `-` is legal in text (making a small hyphen) or math (making a minus sign) so there is no error raised at the `-` even though the text one is wrong, only when it hits the `^` which must be in math does it raise the error and then it inserts `$` before that, not because that is the right fix, but because that is the only thing it can do to get itself back on track to process the document further.